# Java dependency injection problem

Tags: jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, glassfish, ejb-3.0

I'm trying out some j2ee features which comes with Java reflection. Therefore i tried out the JNDI lookup which works without any problem, but I also wanted to try the opposite version "Dependency Injection". However it didn't work so well, and I couldn't find the reason for why either.

Anyway below it is just a simple function, which I just wanted to use to try out the DI feature. However when I compile it now I will get `Exception in thread "main"java.lang.NullPointerException`. Anyone can see where I've made wrong? Btw I'm using Glassfish with it. So have deployed a jar file in the `/<glassfish>/autodeploy folder`

The interface

```
import javax.ejb.*;
@Remote
public interface Hello {

    public void sayHello(Stiring name);
}
```

The implementation

```
import javax.ejb.*;

@Stateless(name = "FooBean", mappedName = "ejb/FooBean")
public class HelloImpl implements Hello {


    @Override
    public void sayHello(String name) {
        System.out.println("Hello " +name);
    }
}
```

The client

```
import javax.ejb.EJB;
public class ClientTest {
    @EJB
    static Hello bdb;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        bdb.sayHello("starcorn");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey I got the problem solved.
Basically I could not run dependency injection as an normal java application. Therefore I had so solve by using Glassfish's appclient.

The things that I needed to do was to pack my Client with my EJB (FooBean) into an EAR project. And then generate a Jar file out of it. Beside that I also had to specifically at `@EJB` rewrite it to `@EJB(name="beanName", unitName="beanUnitName")` more over when I created the EAR jar, I had to specify where the Main class is located.

Answer (score 1):

You can only inject into a managed object. For example a stateless / statefull session bean. In this case it looks like your "client" is not a managed object.

If you really want to go this route you might want to look into spring which will allow you to inject into non managed objects.

Answer (score 0):

You may have missed some steps along the road, hard to say with just the above fragments....
Have a look at [this tutorial on the Netbeans site](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/entappclient.html), it shows the complete procedure.

Comment: I'm using eclipse though it seems the setup part is more tedious

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about J2EE specific but from general Java-ness you never initialize bdb (bdb = new HelloImpl()). So it seems like you're trying to call a non-static method on an uninitialized variable.   If you make sayHello static you wouldn't need to initialize it (or even declare it as a member).

```
public class HelloImpl implements Hello {
    @Override
    public static void sayHello(String name) {
    }
}

public class ClientTest {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        HelloImpl.sayHello("starcorn");
    }
}
```

Comment: nah, it's pretty handy stuff :-)

Comment: Yes as fvu said, I'm trying to use injection thus I don't need to create an instance

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run a main class directly through Eclipse and still get dependency injection.  You must use an [application client container](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2418/beakt.html) in order to get injection.

Comment: Yes I have an application client container. I'm using glassfish for that purpose. However how does one execute the main function? Since I cannot run it by just building the project in Eclipse now. So I guess I have to create a jar file out of my EJB and Client, and then run it in Glassfish's application container, right?

Comment: Did you follow the link?  Specifically the "Using the Embeddable ACC" link?  http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2418/beakv.html#gipkt